# how to convert GETDATE() in a SQL database for a specific format while creating table?

Tags: sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

How can i create a convert function while creating a table, 
my following sql script for creating table is.

```
CREATE TABLE database.dbo.Machine
   (HistoryID bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    MachineId bigint,
    HistoryDate datetime2(0) DEFAULT GETDATE(),
  );
GO
```

This above code gives me the datetime format in yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss
I need to convert this GETDATE() in **HH:mm:ss dd-mm-yyyy**, i can use a query `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'HH:mm:ss dd-mm-yyyy')` But how can include this while creating a table script itself in my above script. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `CONVERT` with appropriate format masks:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 105) AS ts;
```

[image]

### Demo